# Firebase : Google OAuth2 signin fails

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

I have just released app in play store, but there is problem in google signin. If i directaly insall signed apk then google login work perfactly. but when i download app from play store google login doesnt work. It gives me below error.

```
E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, 
please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```

I already added debug and release sha1 to firebase console. Please let me know if i missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a configuration issue with Firebase, Google API console and your google-services.json file.

You need to know that the `release APK` and `debug APK` have **different SHA1** and **different API keys** for Google Services. So you need to add both of them in inside Firebase Project Setting.

After adding both you need to redownload the `google-services.json` file and put it in the right place of your project. Create a fresh release build with your keystore and publish you app once again in Google Play Store.

Should work.

Comment: I had already added SHA1 for release and debug apk. but what you mean by "different  API keys" for debug and release apk. how can i add this in firebase console?

Comment: There is a `SHA-1 Debug Mode key` which is diffrent that the `SHA-1 Release Mode key`. For the first one you need to use `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\YourLocation\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` and for the second `keytool -exportcert -alias AppName -keystore D:\YourLocation\YourApp.keystore.jks -list -v`

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes Somehow it helps me. but exact steps which i mentioned in my answers

Answer (score 0):

This issue with the wrong (not added) SHA1 in **google-services.json**

To solve this you need to add SHA1 for `publish apk` as well in firebase console project.

1. generate SHA1 for debug

   **keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore**
2. generate SHA1 for release

   **keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias your-key-name -keystore path-to-production-keystore**
3. Add SHA1 for publish apk

   I went to my **Release Management tab**, then scrolled down to **App Signing**, and found the **SHA-1** there.

After adding all these **SHA-1** in firebase console. you need to again download **google-services.json** and put in android project. generate signed apk again and publish it. It will works.